# Julia - Threaded loop on multiple DataFrames

Tags: multithreading, dataframe, loops, julia

I would like to do same operations on multiple dataframes through a threaded loop.

The names of the dataframes are for example "Res" and "Delta". Here is the code to generate them :

```
Res = DataFrame(Segment = ["AA","AA","BB","BB"],
                PVFP1 = [10,25,13,10],
                PVFP2 = [8,4,22,20],
                PVFP3 = [150,700,120,100],
                PVFP4 = [145,650,80,50]                
                )
Delta = DataFrame(Segment = ["AA","AA","BB","BB"],
              PVFP1 = [4,13,25,7],
              PVFP2 = [6,7,21,19],
              PVFP3 = [111,456,689,475],
              PVFP4 = [456,253,20,45]                
              )
```

After that I try to pass the same operations on this 2 DF (in real more than that).
What I would like is to pass the operations(described below) on each DF, modifying them and store the modified DF (with their initial name) in the global scope,  to use them after or export to csv.

I tried something but my syntax is probably too aproximative to have a chance... :

```
numcols = names(Res, findall(x -> eltype(x) <: Union{Missing,Number}, eachcol(Res)))
table_list=(Res,Delta)

@threads for X in table_list
   X = @chain X begin
       groupby(:Segment)
       combine(numcols .=> sum, renamecols=false)
       stack(Not(:Segment))
       transform!(:variable => ByRow(x -> match(r"([^\d]+)(\d+)", x).captures) => [:Item, :Year])
       unstack([:Segment, :Item], :Year, :value, renamecols = x -> Symbol("Year", x))
   end
   return X
end
```

I globally understand that this code couldn't work but I am not able to find the right way to make it work.
If you have any suggestions, it will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would have to be something like:

```
numcols = names(Res, findall(x -> eltype(x) <: Union{Missing,Number}, eachcol(Res)))
table_list=(Res,Delta)

results = Vector{DataFrame}(undef, length(table_list))
@threads for i in 1:length(table_list)
   results[i] = @chain table_list[i] begin
       groupby(:Segment)
       combine(numcols .=> sum, renamecols=false)
       stack(Not(:Segment))
       transform!(:variable => ByRow(x -> match(r"([^\d]+)(\d+)", x).captures) => [:Item, :Year])
       unstack([:Segment, :Item], :Year, :value, renamecols = x -> Symbol("Year", x))
   end
end
```

(I have not tested it as your code is not runnable stand alone)

Comment: It works fine and makes it clearer to me how to loop on a list with DataFrames. Thanks a lot